# Propagation speed of telegraph signals

Tags: power, transistors, sensor

Time transfer in the late 19th c was best achieved by telegraph, a major improvement in the determination of longitude for geodetic surveying. A question was posed, to acquire a high accuracy time, by the use of telegraph, how much signal delay would be attributed to the signal propogation over telegraph lines?

How much delay would a telegraph signal have in a 900 mile telegraph time transfer?

Comment: Can't you calculate it? The signal propagation time is roughly the speed of light.

Comment: It's the speed of light, less a bit for dielectrics around the line, less a lot more if the link used loading coils to equalise the LR and CG ratio for low distortion signalling.

Comment: "_A major achievement in longitude determination in geodetic surveying._" This is not a sentence. There is no verb. It makes no sense and it is not clear why you think there is a connection between telegraph and surveying. What does "time transfer" mean? Do you mean "transit time"? Please edit your question.

Comment: The electrical delay would be negligible if the message had to go through another operator or two.

Comment: @transistor time transfer is about synchronization of clocks in the victorian age so that railway timetables made sense. Before that requirement each town and village/district calculated local time without considering others.

Comment: And synchronization of time is how longitude is measured. So, I was curious how much consideration would be in the signal delivery time. I think little, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wow, usually there's a bunch of backlash for homework questions!

Comment: @transistor http://enwp.org/Time_transfer

Comment: See also the NTP protocol ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol ) allowing you to synchronize time even if latency is unknown (assuming it's symmetric or you have multiple peers).

Answer (score 7):

900 miles at *c* is about 4.8 miliseconds. The propagation may be slightly slower; coaxial cable propagates at about 2/3 *c*.

This is still a consideration today; see the famous [500 mile email bug](http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail.html).

Comment: The funniest thingis that on one wire there are many bits at tthe same time, like it were bubbles in a water pipe

Comment: Well, they're just waves; this is why the "wave propagation through a slinky" demo is good for understanding transmission lines.

Comment: Waves are the fronts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that old telegraph lines had a propagation velocity significantly worse than 2/3 c, especially pre-Heaviside, but I'd need to do some heavy research to get any kind of numbers. I expect the delay is still small compared to the accuracy of Victorian clocks, and in any case if you have a round-trip circuit you can cancel out the delay.

Comment: A letter from George Stokes to William Thomson (Lord Kelvin), published in the Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society in 1855, mentions a "retardation" (propagation delay) in a 200-mile telegraph cable from London to Brussels, of 100 milliseconds:https://archive.org/stream/philtrans02617140/02617140#page/n12/mode/1up

Comment: @hobbs: That's an interesting find, but 200 miles in 100 ms is only 1% of c, and Stokes explicitly seems to interpret the delay as a switching time, not a propagation time.

Comment: @BenCrowell You're right, the real vf of the cable was too high to be measured by that method (which is why he calls it "effectively instantaneous"), but *effectively* it's very low because of the very slow rise time caused by poor matching. And that rise time would have gone up with the length of the cable (as the distributed capacitance went up). So practically speaking, the rate a signal moved really was that slow.

Comment: but if someone really wanted to do an accurate time transfer experiment in the 19th century they could do it with *two* identical telegraph cables. Each side keys down at 12:00:00 exactly, and simultaneously records the time they receive the signal from the other side, then communicates it back to the other. The average of the two readings gives the delay (which is assumed to be identical on the two paths, and ignored) and the difference of the two readings gives the difference in clocks between one station and the other.